# Youtube playlist api returns partial data

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've been trying to get tags for youtube videos using playlists/playlistItems api.

I've seen other questions about this and saw there's a possibility to do it with more than one call (make a call to get the videos, which has the tags). 
For example: [How to retrieve a YouTube video's tags with YouTube v3 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240499/how-to-retrieve-a-youtube-videos-tags-with-youtube-v3-api), [YouTube API - get tags for all videos with playlist query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022009/youtube-api-get-tags-for-all-videos-with-playlist-query)

BUT I see in their api documentation that the snippet in playlists api is supposed to include tags:

[image: youtube documentation for playlists]

But it doesn't!
The url I'm using: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelIdz=&key=

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I tried to call this method on my own playlist with my own videos but same result. Also with [`PlaylistItems`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) too.

Comment: @moshfeu do you know how to report bugs, except for using their "send feedback" (which I already did almost a month ago)?

Comment: Looks like they have an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). Also, Maybe you can ask in the [product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube) or in the [google group of youtube api](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube-api-gdata).