# Can we get tags from YouTube Analytics API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I read its possible to get tags from Youtube Data API v3. [YouTube API - get tags for all videos with playlist query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022009/youtube-api-get-tags-for-all-videos-with-playlist-query)
But I was wondering if the same is possible FROM Youtube Analytics API?
Thanks for the help

But I was wondering if the same is possible FROM Youtube Analytics API?
Thanks for the help